# Mathematical induction solution I don't understand

Tags: induction

$$T(k) = 2T(\frac{k}{2})+k^2$$
$$T(k)\leq 2(c(\frac{k}{2})^2\log(\frac{k}{2}))+k^2$$
$$T(k)\leq \frac{ck^2\log\frac{k}{2}} { 2} + k^2$$
$$T(k)\leq \frac{ck^2logk}{2} - \frac{ck^2}{2} + k^2$$
$$T(k)\leq ck^2logk$$

There's something I don't understand with the last two lines. I don't know how the $$- \frac{ck^2}{2}$$

got there. Is it just basic math I'm missing?

Comment: i think the term should be  $- \log(2) \frac{ck^2}{2}$ instead of $\frac{ck^2}{2}$.

Comment: No, I double-checked it in the book and that's what it says..

Comment: Are you using base-2 logarithms here?

Comment: Yes, it's from a book we use in Computer Science in school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log\frac{k}{2} = \log k - \log 2$$ and so: $$\frac{ck^2\log\frac{k}{2}}{2} = \frac{ck^2(\log k - \log 2)}{2} = \frac{ck^2\log k}{2} - \frac{ck^2\log 2}{2}$$

If $\log$ is here the base-2 logarithm, then $\frac{ck^2\log 2}{2} = \frac{ck^2}{2}$, and you're done.  If you're using some other base, then your book appears to have an error in it.

Comment: You are brilliant. Exactly what I missed, properties of logarithms. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so how was the final answer derived?

Comment: @Gannicus: Which part, exactly?

Comment: The one where: T(k) ≤ (ck^2logk)/2− (ck^2)/2 + k^2. How did it arrive to the final answer?

Comment: @Gannicus: You haven't shown enough of the problem for me to know for sure what's going on (How is $T(k)$ defined?  What is $c$?), but if $c\geq 2$, then $1 - c/2\leq 0$, and so $k^2(1-c/2) = k^2 - \frac{ck^2}{2}\leq 0$, and if $ck^2\log k\geq 0$, then: $$T(k) \leq \frac{ck^2\log k}{2} - \frac{ck^2}{2} + k^2 \leq \frac{ck^2\log k}{2} \leq ck^2\log k$$